# USB file transfer on iOS

Tags: iphone, usb, ios, file-transfer

I want to write an app that stores its data in a file that can be retrieved and transfered to the user's PC. Does the iOS support file transfers over USB (through my app or through a mass storage device type feature). Preferably, I do not want to write a client for the PC to receive the files, and I want to prompt the user about new files when they plug in their device to their PC if possible. Do the iOS frameworks support these features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, this is available in newer versions of iOS (3.2 and above).  See [here for details on "File-Sharing Support"](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094) (explained for users in [this KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094)).

Comment: These links are broken. Now they just go to the general iOS App Programming page.

Comment: Indeed, the document is gone and Apple's own links redirect.